# = operator applied to nullable types in VB

Tags: vb.net, operators, nullable

I am quite surprised that in C#:

```
int? a = null;
int? b = null;
intc = a == b; //c = true
```

While in VB:

```
Dim a As Integer? = Nothing
Dim b As Integer? = Nothing
```

if( a = b ) generates an exception because the condition a = b is apparently resolved to Nothing (instead of true in C#)

I suppose I can change my condition to:
if( (a Is Nothing AndAlso b Is Nothing) OrElse a = b)
but I find this ugly!
Is there a more elegant way of writing this so simple condition?

Comment: In short: in VB.NET it has sql meaning: `Nothing` means "unknown", if you compare an unknown value `a` with an unknown value `b` the result is: _unknown_ so `Nothing`. In C# two `null`s are `equal`.